# Solving $z''(x)=a\,z'(x)+b(x)\,z(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anybody know a good starting point to solve the ODE

$$z''(x)=a\,z'(x)+b(x)\,z(x) \;,$$

where $a$ is some constant and $b$ some function?

Comment: You want a general method for any b?

Comment: I guess this will be hard. I am rather looking for a general ansatz, which might work for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general closed-form solution.  You might try power series.